# How to format a number with exact of decimal number without rounding in javascript?

Tags: javascript, format

Let say i have a number

```
const number = 122.333444555666
```

i want  to write a function that will return the exact decimal's number that i want. For example

```
formatFunction(number, 5) return 122.33344
formatFunction(number, 7) return 122.3334445
formatFunction(number, 12) return 122.333444555666
formatFunction(number, 15) return 122.333444555666000
formatFunction(number, 20) return 122.33344455566600000000
```

I tried with toFixed() but i end up with some exception . For ex

```
12.111222333.toFixed(18) return '12.111222333000000617'
```

I also try Intl but it always rouned up. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is that `12.111222333` and `12.111222333000000617` are the same number. Even `12.111222333.toString()` will produce `"12.111222333000000617"`. There is no issue with `toFixed`. If you need all the decimal digits in `12.111222333`, you'll have to use a library for big decimals instead of plain JS numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with floats I like to split at the decimal place and treat both sides as whole numbers. It makes operating on them a bit easier and increases accuracy.

```
const [wholeNumber, decimals] = num.split(".");
```

Isolating decimals as a string allows us to quickly compare it to they desired scale, enabling us to determine whether to add or subtract.

```
if (decimals.length < scale) {
    const diff = scale - decimals.length;
    const trailingZeros = new Array(diff).fill(0).join("");
    decimals += trailingZeros;
}
```

In the above example we have less decimal places than the desired scale. So we'll create a string of zeros based on the difference to match the scale, then append it to the end of the decimal string.

```
if (decimals.length > scale) {
   decimals = decimals.substr(0, scale);
}
```

When the decimals places are greater, we can use substr() to cut up to the desired scale.

```
return join(wholeNumber, decimals)
```

Lastly we want to rejoin our two sets of numbers using the helper. Note that to satisfy the trailing zeros the answer is returned as a string. Converting it to a number would omit them.

```js
function formatFunction(number, scale) {
    // if it's a number need to convert to string
    const num = typeof number === 'number' ? number.toString() : number;
    let [wholeNumber, decimals] = num.split(".");

    if (decimals.length < scale) {
        const diff = scale - decimals.length;
        const trailingZeros = new Array(diff).fill(0).join("");
        decimals += trailingZeros;
    } else if (decimals.length > scale) {
        decimals = decimals.substr(0, scale);
    }
    // decimals.length === scale
    return join(wholeNumber, decimals)
}

// helper
function join(wholeNumber, decimals) {
    if (!decimals) return wholeNumber;
    return [wholeNumber, decimals].join(".")
}
const number = 122.333444555666;
console.log(formatFunction(number, 5)) // return 122.33344
console.log(formatFunction(number, 7)) // return 122.3334445
console.log(formatFunction(number, 12)) // return 122.333444555666
console.log(formatFunction(number, 15)) // return 122.333444555666000
console.log(formatFunction(number, 20)) // return 122.33344455566600000000
```

Comment: I don't know it's the best solution or not but simple worked for me! Thank you!